# Opentelemetry show invoker in a span

Tags: open-telemetry

I setup opentelemetry with autoconfiguration.
Now what I see on Jaeger is series of spans orginazed under traces. So I can see spans like "http get some-external-service/path" which is fine.

What to do when I would like to see which part of my code was the invoker of the service?

Can I append that information somehow to the span?

As for reading this: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/java/instrumentation/
I think I can do it when manually setting up traces and spans but that would be a huge amount of work and making the codebase unreadable.

is there any centralized way to do it ?

Comment: @Gaurang  Thanks, exactly what I needed. If you move this comment to an answer I will accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using Java agent you can use `@WithSpan`, annotate methods invoking external services with `@WithSpan` annotation which will create a span of the invoking method and another service span should be visible under this span. More Details on `@WithSpan` here https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/java/automatic/annotations/